# is it possible to know the exact location of a bluetooth device in range?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am planning to build an android app that:

when downloaded and activated - automatically detects blue tooth phones in range and sends a signal to me  by text message or just makes my phone ring or make a sound. So  can I make the Phone display a picture or map to show where the Bluetooth devices are?

e.g If I am walking on the road - I would like to know which Bluetooth signals are coming from Left , right, behind or in front - is this possible???

Comment: No, since the antennae is omnidirectional you cannot know what direction the signal is coming from, and BT signals don't embed any intrinsic location data.

Answer (score 0):

I think no , you can not accurately determine the source of the radio signal only one receiver

Answer (score 0):

[Bluetooth API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html) is meant for sharing information via text or byte format. It does not provide any location based information like latitude or longitude information for a particular device. Hence answer is clearly **No**.